# DefaultMediaItemTextExtractor: Cannot extract content from media item with id - Expected pdf format

Tags: azure, media-library, indexing

While reindexing my master / web indexes, the reindex failed and I saw these error messages in the logs:

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.Common.DefaultMediaItemTextExtractor

Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
Message: Expected pdf format
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.Readers.PdfSharpReader.ValidateIsPdf(String path)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.Readers.PdfSharpReader.ReadAll(String filePath)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.Common.DefaultMediaItemTextExtractor.ExtractTextFromMedia(MediaItem mediaItem)
```

On further inspection, the media library items in question did in fact have PDF files attached, but when I downloaded the attachment, its size was 0 bytes. However, the PDF must have had a size at some point, because the `Size` field has a value greater than 0.

[image: media item fields]

How might this have happened? Worth noting is that the solution does make use of Azure blob storage to store media items.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the blob of the media item (the actual media data) no longer exists in the configured blob storage provider - in your case Azure Blob storage.

As a first step, check the credentials for the Azure Blob storage provider still work correctly as perhaps it is just a permission issue reading the blob.

Some other scenarios to consider that could lead to this issue:

- Another Sitecore instance connected to the same storage endpoint and perhaps deleted that media item
- Your instance or another instance ran the [blob migration tool](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/use-the-blob-migration-tool.html) and didn't complete the process correctly